# How to send a rule for another agent in Jason?

Tags: agent, multi-agent

Jason comes with a demo that use the performative "tellRule" to send rules, but in my tests it is not working. I tried to send to the self agent like this:

```
.send(self,tellRule, [{a :- b & c}])
```

The result was:

> ```
> Command .send(self,tellRule, [{a :- b & c}]): included for execution
> Communication error -- no_applicable: Found a goal for which there is no applicable plan:+!kqml_received(self,tellRule,[{ a :- (b & c)}],mid511)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Jason has not "tellRule" performative defined by default. In fact, the mentioned [demo](https://github.com/jason-lang/jason/tree/master/demos/tell-rule) is teaching how to add a KQML performative. So, to your code work, you should first create "tellRule", doing like this:

```
.send(self, tellHow, {+!kqml_received(A,tellRule,Rules,_) <- 
    .print("Received rule(s) ",Rules, " from ",A); 
    for ( .member(R, Rules) ) 
    {+R[source(A)];}  
    .relevant_rules(_,LR);       
    .print("Rules: ",LR)}).
```

After this, you can run the command:

```
.send(self,tellRule, [{a :- b & c}]).
```

By the way, the same idea can be used to create something like "untellRule":

```
.send(self, tellHow, {+!kqml_received(A,untellRule,Rules,_) <-      
    .print("Removing rule(s) ",Rules, " from ",A);      
    for ( .member(R, Rules) )      
    {-R}}).
.send(self,untellRule,[{a :- b & c}]).
```

Comment: In the case of the demo, the receiver.asl already has the plan to handle the tellRules on the receiver side. The tellHow proposed by Cleber is necessary when the receiver hasn't a proper plan for tellRule.